Android gradle conventional plugins publishing - Multi module with build-logic
I have an android multi module project with structure similar to https://github.com/android/nowinandroid
The project root project has 3 key modules core, build-logic and app as below
|-MyProject
  |- build-logic
    |-src
     |-plugins
       |-test-conventional-plugin.gradle.kts
       |-android-lib-plugin.gradle.kts
       |-java-lib-plugin3.gradle.kts
       |-conventional-for-publishing.gradle.kts

   |-build.gradle.kts
  |-Core
    |-datastore
    |-analytics
  |-App  
  |- setting.gradle

The build-logic is included into root project as below so that the conventional plugins are accesible for all modules.
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("build-logic")
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

conventional-for-publishing.gradle.kts defines code for publising android or java libs. Now I want to publish the plugins that are contained with in build-logic.plugin for external apps to consume. How can I achive it with the current project pattern. If it cannot be acheived with the structure, suggest me a way to publish these plugins or explain your thoughts. Thanks.
Added publising code to build-login > build.gradle.kts. Trying to find way to use the existing publising code instead of duplicating the publish code.
